# Expand bootstrap's collapsed navbar to the bottom no matter the content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, navbar

So I'm trying to make a personal responsive navbar with bootstrap and I can't figure out how to expand the collapsed menu to the bottom of the window no matter the content (with the default navbar, it expands with the content)

[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/Fuw9I3ycWx)

Comment: Do you want to expand the height of the collapsed navbar?